# Sortable list contains between given numbers jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to use sortable list between given numbers in data-id
I used a code to update data-id on drug. but my code updating from 1 to 6
I want it as 11 to 16
or 21 to 26 ....
so I just want the top or starting data id will be always starting data-id
But now it's becoming 1 always

```js
jQuery('.photos').sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui){
        $(".ui-sortable li").each(function(i, el){
               $(el).attr('data-id',$(el).index()+1);
        });
    }
});
```

```css
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; cursor:move; }
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
#sortable li.fixed{cursor:default; color:#959595; opacity:0.5;}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul class="photos ui-sortable">
    <li class="photo" data-id="11">pawal</li>
    <li class="photo" data-id="12">sigma</li>
    <li class="photo" data-id="13">notea</li>
    <li class="photo" data-id="14">missouri</li>
    <li class="photo" data-id="15">Ooops</li>
    <li class="photo" data-id="16">Ratee</li>
</ul>
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/c2e7z4dq/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.each` is taking in the iterator variable `i` it begins at the first index of the collection `0` and goes to the last element in the collection, if you want a custom value you should declare a variable and initialize it to x and increment it by 1 on each iteration of the `.each` loop

Change this piece of code:

```
jQuery('.photos').sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui){
        let myIncrementor = GetLowestDataIdValue(); //Custom value returned from function
        $(".ui-sortable li").each(function(i, el){
               $(el).attr('data-id',myIncrementor);
               myIncrementor += 1; //increment it
        });
    }
});

function GetLowestDataIdValue(){
    let lowestVal = -1;
    $('.photos.ui-sortable').find('li').each(function(i, el){
         if(parseInt($(el).attr('data-id')) < lowestVal || lowestVal === -1){
               lowestVal = parseInt($(el).attr('data-id'));
         }
    });

    return lowestVal;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8bheapqf/)

Comment: I want first value will take from list item. Not as static    11 from given value.  Can u pls suggest

Comment: @LemonKazi So you want the lowest data-id value of the collection to initialize myIncrementor correct?

Comment: Yeah u r right . Lowest one will be starting number

Comment: @LemonKazi Ok. Please see my updated answer, here is a working fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/c2e7z4dq/17/)